# UIImagePicker source type doesn't want to change

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I've set an UIImagePicker with a `.savedPhotosAlbum` as a sourcetype in order to develop an app.

```
import UIKit

class PictureViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    /////////////////// OUTLETS ////////////////////
    ///////////////// PROPERTIES ///////////////////
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imagePicker.delegate = self

    }

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        // Where do we want our photos from and we don't want edited photos
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
        imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

        // Let's take the image from the picker
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        snapImage.image = image

        // When the user picks a picture, disabling the background color of the UIImageView
        snapImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        // Closing the image picker
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func cameraTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Now that my app is finished I want to try my app on my Iphone so I changed this :

```
imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
```

to

```
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
```

And I have added in my `info.plist`

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We want to access your camera to ...</string>
```

But when I try to take a picture, it keeps showing me my photos album and that is the problem.
I want to be able to take a picture from the camera of my phone.

Comment: You need to put more context so put your code where you are checking for device and presenting `picker`

Comment: @Santosh First time posting about IOS sorry, I've added all I've got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put this code

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

in either `viewDidLoad` or `cameraTapped`

**Problem** - As right now you are putting this code in the delegate method of `UIImagePicker` which gets called after either picking the image or taking the image.

Comment: Thank you so much for both solution and explanation !